# Translation and interchanging integral and limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth compactly supported function and $g \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. Consider the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|f(y)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|g(x - hy) - g(x)|\, dx\, dy.$$ Is it true that as $h \rightarrow 0$, the above integral tends to 0?

This would be the case if I could interchange integral and limit. Indeed, suppose I could do that. Then
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|f(y)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|g(x - hy) - g(x)|\, dx\, dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|f(y)|\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|g(x - hy) - g(x)|\, dx\, dy = 0$$
since translation is continuous in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. However, how can I justify this interchange of integral and limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
g(y,h)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|g(x - hy) - g(x)|\, dx.
$$
Since
$$
0\leq g(y,h)\leq2\|g\|_{L^1}
$$
for all $y$ and $h$, the function $|f(y)|g(y,h)$ has an integrable majorant.
Therefore you can use the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) and get
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|f(y)|g(y,h)\, dy
=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|f(y)|\lim_{h\to0}g(y,h)\, dy,
$$
as you wanted.